# flutter listview.separate creates an effect on each item while scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I created a widget using Listview.separate() and when I scroll my list,
there is an effect(scrolling effect, i presume) on each item.

here's how it looks when scrolling:

[image]

It may not clear an effect what I talk about, but when you look at image closely,
you can see that there is a blueish effect attached to each item while scrolling.

here's an snippet of my code

```
//main.dart
MaterialApp(
   ...
   ...
   theme: ThemeData(
         brightness: Brightness.dark,
         primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
         primaryColor: backgroundColor[0],
         primaryColorDark: backgroundColor[0],
         primaryColorLight: backgroundColor[0],
         scaffoldBackgroundColor: backgroundColor[0],
         unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white,
   )
)
//screen that uses listview.separate
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: themeBgColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        ...
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child:
        NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
          onNotification: (overScroll){
            overScroll.disallowGlow();
            return true;
          },
          child: ListView.separated(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              itemBuilder: (_, __) {
                return Container(
                  height: 30,
                  color: bgContainerColor,
                  child: Text("aaaaaaaaa"),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (_, __) {
                return SizedBox(height: 10);
              },
              itemCount: 100),
        )
```

1. Colors I used for this sample contains no blueish color.
2. I used NotificationListener to remove overScroll effect.

What is this effect and what should i do to remove that blueish color appearing effect while scrolling?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it's not software issue, because i don't see this effect in your video. Usually it happens on AMOLED displays with black color, because for get  black color AMOLED display disable pixel, but when you scroll, it happens too fast.
Discuss: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/blurry-effect-when-scrolling-on-dark-screens.3648468/

Comment: Hi, First of all, thanks for your comment. I posted this question yesterday using macbook pro(m1) at work, and right now I'm using Windows desktop with dell monitor, which is not AMOLED. The funny thing is that, with my desktop, I can also notice that i could not see that blueish effect on items.. Yes i will look into the links that you posted!! thank you so much!!!